# Is the function of two strictly concave functions also concave?

Tags: analysis, functions, convex-analysis

This may be a trivial question to most, but here we go:
I have two strictly concave functions, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
From this can I say that a function of those two functions, $h[f(x), g(x)]$, is also strictly concave?
If this is **not** always true, what are the further conditions on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to ensure strict concavity of $h(\cdot)$?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: What if $h(f(x),g(x)) = -f(x)$? This is never strictly concave if $f$ is. I think the conditions on $h$ may be more relevant than conditions on $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I think you should ask yourself the same question with only one function $f(x)$.
Let $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is a concave function, and $h(x) = \frac 1x$, then $h(f(x)) = \frac {1}{\sqrt x}$ is actually convexe.

So by using an example with only one function, I proved that it's not true for two functions.

Still using one function, I don't think that the conditions should only apply on $f(x)$ but also, and especially, on $h(x)$.

First you should look out for $\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}$ in terms of $h$ and $f$ and then you should be able to make a condition rule.

Only then should you try to generalise it to two functions.

Comment: Thank you for this. Of course, I can work through the second order condition of h(.) and find the conditions that need to hold for it to be concave, but I was wondering whether there is a general rule that guarantees concavity of h(.) under some basic further conditions. For example, I know that both f(x) and g(x) are decreasing in x (at least for the relevant domain) and strictly concave. I'm not sure that is sufficient though. If there is no such rule (i haven't been able to find one, that's why I asked here) then I will just have to use each component of the second order condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example: let $f(x) = g(x) = - x^2$ and $h(f(x), g(x)) = f(x)g(x)$. Clearly $h(f(x), g(x)) = x^4$ which is not concave.